# JS scripts in external file: ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I have following problem:
This is my register.html file with register scripts included

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Customer registration</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="register.js"></script>
</head>
<body>



        <legend>Customer Registration</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control input-md" required="">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Last Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control input-md" required="">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">Email</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="example@example.com" class="form-control input-md" required="">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="password">Password</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control input-md" required="">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="button" value="Register" id="registerBtn" onclick="prepareRegisterData()" class="btn btn-info btn-block">
            </div>
        </div>



</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function prepareRegisterData() {
        let registerData = {
            firstname: $('#firstname').val(),
            lastname: $('#lastname').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            password: $('#password').val()
        };
        register(registerData);
    }

    function register(data) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/customer",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: function() {
                alert("Successfully registered");
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Registration error")
            }
        })
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Everything works ok, but i want to create js file with my function.
I import my script in between head tags in register.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="register.js"></script>
```

and move scripts from script tags in html to register.js file:

```html
function prepareRegisterData() {
    let registerData = {
        firstname: $('#firstname').val(),
        lastname: $('#lastname').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        password: $('#password').val()
    };
    register(registerData);
}

function register(data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/customer",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function() {
            alert("Successfully registered");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Registration error")
        }
    })
}
```

Now if i click register button in console i have

> ReferenceError: prepareRegisterData is not defined

Maybe You know what I missed here?

Comment: While looking at the page, press Ctrl+U to see the source code. Find the `<script>` tag and you should be able to click the `src` part. If you do that, does the browser show your script? (also: in the first snippet you have `<script>` below `<body>` but nothing is supposed to be below `<body>`).

Comment: What is your folder structure ?

Comment: you can also defer the script if you don't want to change the order, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script and https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Comment: @JSLover — The script just defines functions. There's no need to wait for the DOM to load before running the script.

Comment: Assuming there aren't errors generated in the console as the script is loaded (check!), the most likely explanation for the problem is that you just got the URL to the script wrong. Use the Network tab of the browser's developer tools to check.

Comment: I have run it locally. It works fine, I know it sounds silly, But have you saved your files ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, project structure is reason.
I have my .js files under WEB-INF directory, now i have js directory above WEB-INF and everything works
Thanks for help :)